# How do I get the most recent rows in Socrata SODA datasets since the last query?

Tags: socrata, soda

I am using Splunk to analyse SFGov open data (data.sfgov.org), which is a Socrata system.

I am able to download the json data and analyse stuff offline. I am now implementing automated indexing of updates to the datasets (everyday).

I am trying to figure out which Socrata API fields to actually use to get the new records since my last poll.

I know I can use the $where URL option to filter again the :created_at and :updated_at parameters, but is there a rowID or last index or something like that? I will maintain local state on the splunk side on the last fetched row for e.g.

Like if the last row I got last night was 18104, then for tonite's check, I will ask for rows posted > 18104.

Thanks in advance! I am using python for the automation.

------ added 11/02/2016 ---

Currently I am manually testing trying this type of GET (tested it using hurl.it)

https://data.sfgov.org/resource/nwsr-z4mh.json?$where=:created_at between '2016-10-23T18:00:00' and '2016-11-03T00:00:00'&$order=:created_at DESC&$select=:*, *

- this uses the :created_at system field in the Socrata dataset.
- It is returning the records created between those timestamps. That seems to be working.

So if I were to put this into python I need to simply save the previous fetch date-time and do a 'between  and  and hope to get the latest created records.

I prefer a way to refer to a ROW#, but I don't know how to use the id":"row-8aiu.d5x4~8rdi" parameter yet.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're doing the right thing already. You'd just want to save the latest `:created_at` or `:updated_at` and use that in your `$where` for your following query.

You can't do a `$where=:updated_at > :row-...` because row IDs are identifiers, not datetimes.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I also just validated  the created_at approach with SFGov, so it's good to see you take the same view.

Comment: Also one question @chrismetcalf: Is there a definition of row IDs somewhere in socrata docs? I understand I cannot match them against dates, but it will help to know if rowIDs are a random string or if there is a structure to them that can used for filtering criteria.

Comment: For e.g. I am able to extract a row alone by using the row ID in this URL [link] (https://data.sfgov.org/resource/nwsr-z4mh/row-8aiu.d5x4~8rdi.json) but I want understand its literal structure better if there is one at all.

Comment: Row IDs are randomly generated strings, so they don't denote any row ordering.

Comment: Got this @chrismetcalf.

Comment: I've been testing with :created_at. https://data.sfgov.org/resource/nwsr-z4mh.json?$where=:created_at%20%3E%20%272016-12-04T18:00:00%27&$order=date%20DESC&$select=:*,*                        I am seeing an odd response. For a 2016-12-04 created_at, I am seeing records with dates of 2010! Is this normal with Socrata data coming out of SFGov? {":created_at":"2016-12-06T18:47:14.349Z",":id":"row-g7nk.fxxr.d9ww",":updated_at":"2016-12-06T18:47:14.349Z",":version":"rv-nvbt~vu6z.ydz6","date":"2010-04-09T00:00:00.000","desiredoutcome":"Discuss the Mayorâ€™s initiatives in the Mid-Market St. area and